# Installation error: installer_nodejs_windows.msi

Tags: installation, aptana3

Trying to install Aptana Studio 3.6.1 and I get this:

> Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file. CRC
>   error.

Running Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the Node-V5.4.0-x64.msi

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.4.0/

Then Download Node-v0.10.13-x86.msi

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.13/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error,
Error 4155. Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.
MSI (c) (50!54) [13:38:35:815]: Product: Aptana Studio -- Error 4155. Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.

While we wait for a response and a fix, Aptana Studio 2.0.5 installs without errors.  I will use it until Windows 10 install problem with version 3.6.1 is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

for those trying to install `Node-V5.4.0-x64.msi` but don't know how to get it from their page
https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.4.0/
other dist
https://nodejs.org/dist/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your installations file with any Command-line interface (**CLI**/terminal) and run it with the parameters **`/passive`** and **`/norestart`**.

**For example:** `c:\<aptanaPath>\aptana.exe /passive /norestart`.